# grid view page numbers are hidden on RowDataBound

Tags: asp.net, gridview, rowdatabound

I have a grid view and set allow page to true.it worked fine but when I want to invisible some column (such as ID), the page numbers are hidden!

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvVisa" OnRowDataBound="gvVisa_RowDataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvVisa_SelectedIndexChanged" OnPageIndexChanging="gvVisa_PageIndexChanging" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Font-Size="13px" Width="963px">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#00CCFF" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" BorderStyle="None" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="شناسه" DataField="vsiId"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="تصویر ">
            <ItemStyle Width="150" />
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("visImageName") %>' Width="150" Height="100" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText=" نام کشور" ItemStyle-Width="600px" DataField="visCountry">
            <ItemStyle Width="600px"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="وضعیت نمایش " DataField="isActive"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="وضعیت نمایش">
            <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" Width="24px" Height="24px" ImageUrl="~/images/false.png" Visible='<%# !(bool)Eval("isActive") %>' runat="server" />
                <asp:Image ID="Image2" Width="24px" Height="24px" ImageUrl="~/images/true.png" Visible='<%# Eval("isActive") %>' runat="server" />

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="عملیات">
            <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton Text="تغییر وضعیت" Width="100px" CssClass="btns" ID="lnkSelect" runat="server" CommandName="Select" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" BackColor="#333333" ForeColor="White" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
</asp:GridView>
```

binding to DB:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gvVisa.DataSource = from q in new Data.TouristDataContext().Visas select q;
    gvVisa.DataBind();
}
```

page index changing event:

```
protected void gvVisa_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    gvVisa.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
}
```

and Row Data Bound event to invisible some columns:

```
protected void gvVisa_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: Have you bind hour gridview again on page index changed

Comment: or you can simply set visible false in aspx itself, as i saw there is no condition for hiding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before setting visibility, check if it is DataRow:

**EDIT :** With some modification you can fix the issues you mentioned in edited question.

```
protected void gvVisa_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow || e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        // I would rather set display:hidden for ID
        e.Row.Cells[0].Style.Add("display", "none");
        //e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;
    }            
}
```

( `if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRowDataControlRowType.Pager)` is changed to `if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow || e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)`)

[Here's](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6i8p65gmkp0RXZPZ2huRjdyNjg/edit?usp=sharing) the test project I have used. And the output from my test looks like this:

[image]

Comment: @Hamid Talebi - you can download my test project and compare with yours. If you have any other issues, you can append to your question.

Comment: First of all thanks for your effort.I do it Again .with your solution i can hidden a column but can't hide the column's header that you see in your above picture.And i want another prob!!!when i do it for Cells[0] ,all columns shift to right,you can see above picture again (all column shift to left in your solution)!!see new edition of my question...

Comment: @Hamid Talebi - you need minor modification of the code: change if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) to ` if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow || e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)`. See my edited answer.

Comment: sorry,I don't have free time to try your new solution. Thanks you ,it fine worked. ;)